# Pure Ajax sending other vairables with my working file upload

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, file, post

Bit of a silly question, I'm using pure Ajax so no Json etc. I currently have a working file upload php script which gets a file the user uploads by using:

```
$_FILES['my_uploaded_file']
```

and within Ajax it sends it via POST using a formdata variable

However I cannot work out how to send other variables using POST within the same Ajax function for example In my PHP script I would like to have something like:

```
$_POST['id']
```

Any help would be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try calling your ajax page like :

```
upload.php?id=[my_id]
```

or you generate/get the id on php side. If it's the id of the user that uploaded the picture you probably can get it in your ajax file.

Comment: Forgot I could pass variables like that, that beats the method I was going to use if I didn't get an answer. Thank you and will let you know if I get it working.